# Automatic switching to the changed set of TTL inputs

Tags: logic-gates, switching, ttl, 5v, 7400

I have 2 sets of 4 logical inputs.

All inputs are active-low 5V TTL level lines with 4k7 pull-up resistors, as they may be pulled to ground by a a user pressing a switch or flipping a transistor with a rotary encoder, depending on what will be connected, if at all.

**The goal**
is to automatically *pass the inputs of the set that changed* to the output of the circuit;
If any of the inputs on a set changes then the outputs should reflect that set.
If there are successive changes on a set then that sets keeps being passed.

The inputs may be momentarily low, as in pressing a button. It may also kept low continuously, as in flipping a switch, during which time a change may occur in the other set. In such case the circuit should switch to that other set; *a change in any set switches to that set*.

**Constraints**
The outputs will be fed into one of the input sets of an existing [74LS157 multiplier](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls157.pdf?ts=1596222187299&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fen.wikipedia.org%252F) on an existing PCB using 5V TTL logic, so perhaps TTL logic is best suited, and everything should run on 5V.

I like to optimise for minimising the number of ICs and passive components, and also for easy to obtain and cheap components.

**What I came up with**
is a flank detector circuit to generate a pulse on each flank of *each* input line.
[image: Flank Detector]
For each set all 4 detectors are fed into an OR gate to detect change on any line, and then both set's detections are fed into a SR latch to remember the last changed set.
The Latch then feeds a 74157's selection input.  The 74157 then passes the changed set to its output.
All in all that takes around 6 7400 series IC's, 8 capacitors and 8 resistors.

I have a good feeling this can be done simpler.

Comment: a microcontroller may be the lowest cost solution

Comment: have you actually thought this through? ... it seems to me that the output of the circuit may not be as useful as you imagine

Comment: @jsotola I have thought this trough but obviously I might have missed something. Please enlighten me if you see something I do not, or explain why you are sceptical, so it may help me.
As for microcontrollers, that's the obvious go to answer for a lot of things, but it must be low cost, easy to obtain, have 8 TTL inputs and 4 outputs and work on 5V. Also easily programmable and testable and preferably hand-solderable. I'd love to hear your solution as I have no recent microcontrolle experience.

Comment: The task is not clearly defined for logical design. You want registers to remember last state x, and new state, x+1, but no purpose for the change bit , async or synchronous, rate, Basically compare states if not equal to create a clock for some purpose? why?

Comment: this is my understanding .... two groups of inputs ... group A and group B ... one switch on each group ... press switch A ... output connects to group A .... press switch B ... output connects to group B .... release switch A ... output connects to group A .... is this how the circuit should behave?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I don't care about the last state, only the current state of the inputs. The 4 input-set which changed last should be on the output. No clock, asynchronous. It's for automatically switching to the human interface input that has changed the most recently.

Comment: @jsotola Yes. Only that each group consists on 4 data lines which have a switch each. Any flip of the switch in a group will trigger outputting that group.

Comment: As  with all interrupts, when there is contention even if unlikely, one must rank higher than the other just as for Q output S over-rides R , so a 1-shot XOR change must be kept as short as possible to Latch the last change S or R to select the most recent input change.

Comment: this seems like an X-Y problem ... what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jsotola I have one 4-pin human interface device going into the described PCB that I want to expand to two devices on the same 4 pins. These two new interface devices will both be connected at the same time. I don't want the user to have to swich them manually, rather I want the circuit to detect which interface is currently being used and pass the state of that one on.
An 'intelligent' 4-way switch if you will.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I realise that however unlikely there may be contention and S&R may be active together but it won't matter much if in that case data is lost or which input wins. You can expect 1 user to operate the inputs, and not at the same time, and he will continue to do so until he accomplishes what he wants.

Comment: There have been a lot of follow-questions and I realise I may not have been clear enough and perhaps I have to rewrite the entire Question and add more pictures to better define it. If you think so, please let me know and I will tomorrow.

Comment: @durandal ok, i am officially confused ... suppose device A has state 0101 and device B has state 0000  ... A had focus .... device B changes to 0100   ....  how will you know that 3rd bit of B changed and not 1st bit of A?

Comment: " how will -you- know that 3rd bit of B changed and not 1st bit of A? " The 'you' is a bit ambiguous there so I do not exactly know what you mean. The circuit knows because it is monitoring all input bits - that may be the core of the question: how do you do that efficiently? You, as user, does not have to know but know anyway because you know which input device you are moving or pressing. Lets say it's a track ball then you expect the pointer to move. If it's a keypad you expect a digit to appear on screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have found the simplest way to do it in discrete logic.

You could perhaps use a 4 input XOR to combine your inputs and then use a single flank detector, but this could fail if two buttons are activated at exactly the same time.

You could perhaps use a 5 channel mux and find a way to use the spare channel as the flip-flop

As you only need your logic to be faster than a finger it may be easier to use a cheap mirocontroller module like an arduino uno clone.

Comment: Yes, I am going the microconroler route as that will result in a cheaper solution with fewer active components. Thank you.